# GitLab CI Read File from Other Repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In the setup that I have, there are two repositories in GitLab, one of which has a version file that the other needs for naming the artifact produced by its CI/CD pipeline.

Right now, I'm just cloning the entire other repository to access that `VERSION` file. I tried using `git archive` to pull only the `VERSION` file but the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` doesn't work with SSH access remotes (from my testing), and doing a `curl` to the raw file path doesn't work because its on a private GitLab instance.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 20):

I had the same Problem and solved it by using an access token. Go to **User Settings** > **Access Tokens** and create one:

[image: Generate access token]

Using that you then can pull files from all repositories via [gitlab-api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository).

```
wget --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_token>" http://mygitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/files/path%2Fto%2Ffile/raw?ref=master
```

To pull that file in the GitLab CI you can set your access token as environment variable. Go to  > **Settings** > **CI** > **Environment variables** and add `GITLAB_TOKEN` with your access token:

[image: add ci environment variable]

You now can use that environment variable in your CI script to download that file with `wget` or `curl` if you prefer.

```
wget --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" http://mygitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/files/path%2Fto%2Ffile/raw?ref=master
```

or

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" http://mygitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/files/path%2Fto%2Ffile/raw?ref=master
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Just wanted to add that you can use the baked-in CI variable `$CI_API_V4_URL` if the upstream project is on the same instance, like this: `curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" ${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/<project_id>/repository/files/path%2Fto%2Ffile/raw?ref=master`

Comment: But my git returns me only 404 not found on such type of address :(

Comment: I must add that in paths to files all slashes must be escaped with %2F. So, if your file path is 'myfolder/lala.txt", then url is: ${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/<project_id>/repository/files/myfolder%2Flala.txt/raw?ref=master

Answer (score 1):

A "not very nice" way I do it is putting a registered in my GitLab user settings SSH key in the container that runs the job which gives me access to all repos I have privileges to.

If you need just one file from the other repo thing that comes to mi mind (although I wouldn't call it a great solution either) is saving this file on GitLab pages in the "other" repo in CI and then just getting it with curl.

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP/s still the option "Allow access to this project with a CI_JOB_TOKEN" under CI/CD>Settings ready in the remote repo allowing source one, and using the header JOB-TOKEN:$CI_JOB_TOKEN seems suitable,

```
before_script:
  - mkdir -p /from/other/repo
  - curl --output /from/other/repo/file1.txt --header "JOB-TOKEN:$CI_JOB_TOKEN" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/<nnnn>/repository/files/the%2Fpath%2Ffile1.txtyaml/raw?ref=master"
```

Comment: It works probably for public repos, JOB-TOKEN is not supported for accessing private repos: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html